# How to Integrate native android .aar file in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, flutter-dependencies, aar

I have a flutter project,where i have to add native android sdk i.e .aar file.

I have added file path in build gradle.But im getting error
missing plugin exception no channel found.

[image: This is the function writen in dart file]

[image: This is how i declared in mainActivity.kt file]

I dont know where im exactly missing..Kindly help me out

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.